# Validate route from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, node.js, mongoose, axios

I have the following schemas on my mongodb

```
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const Schema    = mongoose.Schema;
const gda       = require('../components/gestao-armarios');

let EncomendaSchema = new Schema({
  itens: {
    type    : [ItemSchema],
    validate: {
      validator:  function(v){
          return v.length >= 1;
      },
      message : 'An order must have at least one product.'
    }
  }  
});



let ItemSchema = new Schema({
  idProduto   : {
    type      : Number,
    required  : true,
    validate: {
      validator:  function(v){
        if (v === 0) return true;
        return gda.get('/api/produto/${v}');
      }
    }
  },

  preco   : {
    type      : Number,
    required  : [true, 'Price is required.']
  },

});
```

I need to verify the existence of an Item on another api but no matter what kind of idProduto I pass to the ItemSchema I get the following error

```
"data": [
        {
            "message": "Validator failed for path `idProduto` with value `1`",
            "field": "idProduto"
        }
```

It's not a connection problem since if I run this

```
let longString = gdm.get('/api/produto/1').then(produto => console.log(produto));
console.log('%s', longString);
```

I receive all the info regarding that particular route.

Is testing that one particular route exists not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

```
gda.get('/api/produto/${v}')
```

=>

```
gda.get(`/api/produto/${v}`)
```